# Case insensitive match in solaris awk regex match

Tags: awk, solaris

in red-hat i can use the 'i' flag, /regex/i
in solaris it doesnt work and I'm looking for a way to do it also.
my script is:

```
ls -1 /webapp/dir/bin | awk '/AR[0-9]+/ && /SMF_LOG/ {dp_pkg=substr($NF,index($NF,"AR")+2); print $NF"@"dp_pkg}' | sort -k2 -t '@' -nr | head -n1 | cut -d'@' -f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 awk '[Aa][Rr][0-9]+ && [Ss][Mm][Ff]_[Ll][Oo][Gg] ...'
```

and a similar pattern match instead of `index` in the rule. Or, if this is an option, translate all chars to upper (or lower) case before you process them, e.g. with `tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"`.

Comment: Hmm but then I index($NF,"AR") .... "AR" is constant. using tr will make me lose the original capitalization from ls..i need it to copy files

Comment: Which is why I suggested replacing index with a pattern matching function as well. Since you want to copy files, can you please rephrase the question in terms of what you want to copy where? I.e. tell us the actual problem, not the problem with this particular solution attempt :-)

Comment: the problem is, ls -1 gives a list of dirs which end with AR123-1 or AR123 or AR542 or some natural number digit and optionally a '-1' or '-2' (a '-' with some number) I would like to sort my results based on this ARXXXXX things

Comment: Are there always 3 digits before the optional `-`? Can the `AR` also be `ar`? Please provide a reasonable complete list of filenames and what the sorted input shall look like. I think it can be solved with `sort`. PS: `ls -1` is redundant: if output is not to a terminal, `ls` always outputs one file per line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo abc | awk '{temp=toupper($0)} temp ~ /ABC/'
abc
```